# Script to direct user info correctly

Tags: php, apache

OS: Debian 7 64 bit

I am writing a script to direct users to their own username.info file correctly.
username.info file is in "/home/username/"
Attaching the file served via apache. 
This file is also protected via username/password - "Valid-User" in apache - defaultsites config file. 
Once username/pass is entered, this script must select appropriate username.info file
At the moment only one user is able to access both username.info files in single webpage. Other users .info file is also listed :(

What changes to be made in script so that on entering the username and password, the appropriate usernmae.info file is served .

```
<htm>
<body>
<font face="arial">
<h2>User list</h2>
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $dir = '/etc/mainfile/users/';
  $files = scandir($dir);

  foreach($files as $index=>$file) {
    $data = explode(".", $file);
    if ($data[1] == 'info') {
        printUser($dir,$data[0]);
    }
  }

  function printUser($dir,$user) {
    echo "<h3>$user</h3>";
    $data = file($dir."$user.info");
    foreach($data as $index=>$line) {
      $line = makelink($line);
      echo $line;
    }
  }

  function makelink($input) {
    $parse = explode(' ', $input);
    $input = "";
    foreach ($parse as $token) {
      $br = "<br>";
      if (strpos($token, "://") > 0) {
        $input .= '<a href="' . $token . '">' . $token . '</a> ';
      } else if(substr($token, 1, 3) == '---') {
        $input .= "<hr>";
        $br = "";
      } else {
        $input .= $token." ";
      }
    }
    return trim($input.$br);
  }

  function getScriptVersion() {
    $data = file("/etc/mainfile/version.info");
    return $data[0];
  }
?>
</body>
</htm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re did apache config and after lot of testing found it better to edit apache rewritecond and rules.
Completly Removed the above file, now user goes directly to his docs directory.

Added the following to virtual host using secret as location:

```js
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{LA-U:remote_user} !^$
  RewriteRule ^/secret(.*) /home/%{LA-U:remote_user}/secret$1

  <Location /secret>
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "secret"
    AuthDigestDomain /var/www/secret
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use foreach. It shows all files.
2. Add $dir .= $username if it and pass are correct
3. check for file_exists()